# Running Multiple Scripts in Sahi

Tags: scripting, sahi

I want to run all the scripts one by one sequentially. I've created a suite file and included scripts in suite. When I run a suite, the scripts run in parallel in multiple browsers.  I would like to run them one after the another in a single browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a suite file from a single browser by changing the Threads in the ant target.

```
<target name="runbrowsertests">

        <sahi suite="../userdata/scripts/demo/demo.suite" 
            browserType="firefox" 
            baseurl="http://sahi.co.in/demo/" 
            sahihost="localhost" 
            sahiport="9999" 
            failureproperty="sahi.failed" 
            haltonfailure="false" 
            threads="1"
            >
            <report type="html" />
        </sahi>
    </target>
```

If it still doesn't work, edit browser_types.xml (Click "configure" link on dashboard). Change `<capacity>` to 1 for the browser that you want to run the tests with. Restart Sahi.